# elems is undefined error when trying to loop through elements from querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I seem to be getting an error with some code. A simplified version of it is:

```
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".vat-info");
    if (elems.length) {
        console.dir({ found: elems });
        Object.keys(elems).forEach(function (key){
            console.dir("X: " + key)
            var item = elems[key];
            console.log("got here"); 
        });
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aL2n4ru7/

The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The frustrating part, is that I don't get this error on JSFiddle! But I do get it in the browser normally:

[image]

I don't get whats wrong :/ I was using this syntax:

```
elems.forEach(function (item,i){
            ....
          });
```

But it seems some browsers don't like doing that with a `querySelectorAll()` output, as its an `Object()` and not `Array()`

Comment: No error in the fiddle console!!!

Comment: wouldn't `[...querySelectorAll('.vat-info')].forEach()` do?

Comment: The error in your screenshot looks to be `TypeError: elems is undefined`, and not `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: The return value from querySelectorAll is array like, but not an array.  And then Object keys on an array doesn't make any sense.  If you want the return value of querySelectorAll to be an array do `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".vat-info");`

Comment: What information do you need from querySelectorAll ? You are doing Object.keys(elem), where elem is an Array.

Comment: @Keith thanks for that. I wasn't aware of `Array.from()`. I assume this is backwards compatible?

Comment: @ShantiswarupTunga I just need to loop through the elements (and then grab data from it - such as class, attributes etc)

Comment: @CertainPerformance mmm weird, you are right! I just tried to get it to replicate that error and now can't. Typcial!

Comment: @Maxum , I did say that in my post:  The frustrating part, is that I don't get this error on JSFiddle! But I do get it in the browser normally:

Comment: FYI it seems `Array.from` isn't available in lots of browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from . They have a polyfill there, so I'm hoping that will do the trick (its hard to know as I don't have any devices that have the issue  - so I will just have to keep an eye on errorception to see what errors pop up).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".vat-info");
 
  if (elems.length) {
            
            elems.forEach(function (key){
                console.log(key.attributes);
                console.log(key.className);
            });
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b19phj2L/3/

Comment: Thanks. I actually had tried: `elems.forEach(function(item, i){` , but in some browsers I got an error